# How to use today's date as file path

Tags: date, path, applescript

I am trying to write a script to create a New Folder in the path:

Macintosh HD : Users : Will : Invoices : TODAY'S YEAR : TODAY'S MONTH

I'm getting something wrong and hope it's a quick and easy fix if anyone has the time.

```
set Fulldate to (current date) as «class isot» as string
set name1 to text 1 thru 4 of Fulldate
set name2 to text 6 thru 7 of Fulldate
property Invoicefolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:Will:Invoices:" & name1 & ":" & name2
tell application "Finder" to make new folder at Invoicefolder with properties {name:"New Folder"}
```

Comment: The folder location needs to exist, including any intermediate folders.  Also, the initial value of a property is set when the script is compiled, so runtime variables can't be used like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that you could take.

Basically, it sets up a list of the necessary folders, including the starting point — the home folder.

It then cycles through that list and attempts to create the next folder level until it has completed all the levels. It does so by appending each new folder name to the prior path.
When it finishes, it will throw up a dialogue to inform you of success or failure.

```
set Fulldate to (current date)

set invoiceFolder to "Invoices" -- name of invoices folder
set yearFolder to year of Fulldate as text -- name of year folder
if Fulldate's month is less than 10 then -- name of month folder
    set monthFolder to "0" & (month of Fulldate as integer)
else
    set monthFolder to (month of Fulldate as integer)
end if

-- set homeFolder to (path to home folder as text) -- containing folder
set homeFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:Will:"
set fList to {homeFolder, invoiceFolder, yearFolder, monthFolder}
set hf to homeFolder -- will expand to include newly made folders

repeat with f from 1 to 3
    tell application "Finder"
        set nextName to item (f + 1) of fList
        try
            set hf to make new folder at hf with properties {name:nextName}
            -- log hf -- optional
        on error
            set hf to hf & nextName & ":" as text
            -- log hf -- optional
        end try
    end tell
end repeat

(*
try -- confirm that folders now exist
    exists hf
    display dialog "It all exists"
on error
    display dialog "Something went wrong and not all folders exist"
end try
*)

tell application "Finder" to make new folder at hf with properties {name:"New Folder"}
```

I have added a couple of lines to log the folder creation results but have commented the lines out. They're not necessary but the logging can show how the path expands as the script cycles through the list.

If conditions change and you with to have more or fewer folder levels — e.g. *dayFolder* — it would be easy to add or remove from the list.

**Updated:** Now creates 'New Folder' in the *month* folder and explicitly uses `"Macintosh HD:Users:Will:"`.

Comment: Using a shell script or AppleScriptObjC will make that script much shorter.

Comment: That's true enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for your help. This script solves another problem which is to create the folders when they do not exist. I should've mentioned that the folders will already have been created but your script is more elegant that what I had hashed together. I am still left with the same problem though, which is how to determine the file path given the current date. I need to save files to the correct folder which in my case would be the month folder of this path Macintosh HD : Users : Will : Invoices : TODAY'S YEAR : TODAY'S MONTH. Obviously this changes every month.

Comment: @willy3oy I put in the starting `Will` path explicitly and added in the 'create new folder' line. I completely missed that. It should automatically use the month based on the current date. Let me know if I'm still misunderstanding your objective.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I needed to happen. Thank you very much for your help with this. I'm learning... slowly